# RestSharp v107 Parameter question adding nested JSON / objects

Tags: c#, json, rest, restsharp

I'm attempting to update my RestSharp calls to v107 and noticed a slight difference in how parameters are added. What I have working in 106 doesn't appear to work in 107.

What I have is that I'm adding an object with nested objects to a POST request. My object looks like this:

```
class CallParameters
{
public CallResources Resources {get;set;}
public CallFilters Filters {get;set;}
}

class CallResources 
{
public bool IncludeOrgData {get;set;}
public bool IncludeDemoData {get;set}
}

class CallFilters
{
public string LastModified {get;set}
public List<string> Users {get;set;}
}
```

I know I can serialize that (once I set the fields) to look like:

```
{"Resources" : {"IncludeOrgData" : true, "IncludeDemoData" : true}, "Filters" : { "LastModifed" : "1/1/21", "Users" : ["User1", User2", "User3"]}}
```

With 106, I was able to create my rest call by serializing my object class to a string and adding it via AddJsonBody like this

```
CallParameters NewCallParameters = new CallParameters();
...Set the fields within the class...
string JsonBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewCallParameters);
var request = new RestRequest { Method = Method.POST };
var client = new RestClient();
var response = client.Execute(request.AddJsonBody(JsonBody));
```

Worked great. Passed over all the parameters right

In 107 I know it's slightly different. Using the same serialize and AddJsonObject, I show a single parameter is added with no name, and the value of the whole serialized object. This causes my call to return

*The request is invalid - An error has occurred*

If I use 'AddObject' to add the entire class CallParamters class as a whole, when I trace through things and look at my request parameters collection, I do see two parameters listed. They are named correctly ('Resources' and 'Filters') but the values are 'MyApp.CallResources' and 'MyApp.CallFilters'. It's like they are not serializing when adding. This returns:

*At least one additional resource is required: IncludeOrgData, IncludeDemoData*

If I add the objects separately as 'CallResourses' and 'CallFilters', I wind up with four parameters names for all the fields within. Value is correct aside from the Users List, which just shows 'System.Collections.Generic.List[System.String]'. Also having four parameters doesn't seem right either and the call also fails with invalid parameters. This returns

*The request is invalid - Resources field is required*

I have experimented with 'AddParamter' some. If I add the whole class as a parameter I'm not sure what to name it. Also the call fails since it has no name. If I add them separately like this:

```
string MyResources = JsonSerializer.Serialize(NewCallParameters.Resources);
string MyFilters = JsonSerializer.Serialize(NewCallParameters.Filters);
request.AddParamter("Resources", MyResources );
request.AddParamter("Filters", MyFilters);
```

I do get two parameters named correctly. The values look good and show all the entries. The return result though from the Rest service I'm calling states

*At least one additional resource is required: IncludeOrgData, IncludeDemoData'*

So it seems it's not seeing the values in the 'Resources' parameter. Do I need to add each as a separate parameter? How would I add nested parameters that way? I feel like I'm close but not getting something.

Answer (score 0):

It helps to read the [documentation](https://restsharp.dev/usage.html#addjsonbody). RestSharp has embedded serialization. Don't serialize your object when using `AddJsonBody`. As you need Pascal-case fields, you'd need to either change JSON options for the default serializer or use the `RestSharp.Serializers.NewtonsoftJson` package.

If you prefer to add a pre-serialized string, use `AddStringBody`

[image]